# Searching a matrix for a chain of sums

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search

I'm still trying to improve on my coding skills, and this question has got me spinning in my tracks a little bit, so any help is greatly appreciated. I know how to create the random array very easily, no problem with that. However, the logic of finding the chain is proving very difficult for me. I believe the proper approach is some sort of depth first searching algorithm, but I'm not entirely sure of how to implement that in this scenario, or whether that is even correct.

My basic question is, should I be using depth first search, and if so, should I be doing it recursively? Any tips or hints on implementation are also welcome!

> Make a program that creates a 3x3 grid of random
>   positive numbers where 0 <= n <= 9. The program should
>   find all possible combinations of numbers that add up to the area of
>   the grid, or 9, using these rules (similar to Boggle):
>
> a. The numbers must be "chained" in sequentially adjacent cells, where
>   "adjacent" cells are those horizontally, vertically, and diagonally
>   neighboring
>
> b. The chain does not have to be in a line. For example, it could go
>   horizontally once, then vertically once, and finally diagonally once
>
> c. At least the “grid width - 1” cells must be used in the chain (a
>   3x3 grid means that at least two cells must be used)
>
> d. A chain cannot repeat a grid cell that it has already used
>
> e. Chains that use the exact same cells as a previous chain are
>   considered repeats and should not be counted

I know that for each element, when you are searching through each adjacent element, you must check and keep track of whether it's been visited before, so you don't repeat numbers.

```
public class GridSolver {
int[][] workingGrid;

public GridSolver(int[][] workingGrid){
    this.workingGrid = workingGrid;
}

public String solve(){
    int length = this.workingGrid.length;
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[length][length];

    for(int rows=0; rows<length; rows++){
        for(int columns=0; columns<length; columns++){
            if(visited[rows][columns] == false){
                dfs(workingGrid[rows][columns]);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}   


public HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> dfs(int element){
    HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> chains = new HashSet<>();

    checkLeft();
    checkTopLeft();
    checkTopMiddle();
    checkTopRight();
    checkRight();
    checkBottomRight();
    checkBottomMiddle();
    checkBottomLeft();

    return null;
}}
```

This is what I have so far and I realize that it is pretty sloppy and not the best thought out scheme, but that's why I'm here I guess :P.

Also just to explain some of my thinking in the code, the `dfs()`method has a return type of HashSet because I know that you can't have duplicate chains, and it is a set of a list of the chains. Also the "check" methods are not implemented, I just wrote them down because I know that you will need to process each of these adjacent blocks for each number.

Once again, any help is greatly appreciated, and thank you for humoring me as a beginner here!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My basic question is, should I be using depth first search, and if so, should I be doing it recursively? Any tips or hints on implementation are also welcome! Sorry, completely forgot to add that into that post, I edited it in.